# Syntax error when include OpenCV core.hpp in SWIG

Tags: c++, opencv, go, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to wrap OpenCV's C++ API. However, when I compile, I got this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.10.1/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:123:
Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.
```

and here is my SWIG file

```
%module example

%{
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
%}

%include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

I'm not sure if this is an error from SWIG or from OpenCV. Is it OK to only include `core.hpp` like this?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you name your swig file?

Comment: I name my swig file by example.swigcxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the problem might be caused by the nested header including.

In `opencv2/core/core.hpp`, there is

```
#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/version.hpp"
```

and hence if I add these two headers to my swig file:

```
%include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"
%include "opencv2/core/version.hpp"
%include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

It will not raise the missing semicolon error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I wrote all the includes needed, but it still gives me this error. Do you know what should I do?